# Hibernate Criteria searching request with One to Many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I've tried to do it like:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class);
cr.createAlias("vendor", "vendor"); 

cr.add( Restrictions.eq("vendor.name", input));

results = (List<Car>) cr.list();
```

And also like:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class);
cr.createCriteria("vendor").add(Restrictions.eq("name", input));

results = (List<Car>) cr.list();
```

Both realizations just return all data, not specified with search query.

In the Car Class I've got relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_vendor", nullable=false)
public Vendor getVendor() {
    return this.vendor;
}
```

And also I've got the`name` column at the `Vendor` class at which I'm trying to search.

So how possibly I could do such search request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your criteria back to the original object.

The reason you get all the cars back is because the line of code adding your vendor into the query creates you a new `criteria` object which you are then not using.

Change:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class);
cr.createCriteria("vendor").add(Restrictions.eq("name", input));  //Does nothing

results = (List<Car>) cr.list();
```

into this:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class);
cr = cr.createCriteria("vendor").add(Restrictions.eq("name", input));

results = (List<Car>) cr.list();
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you wont get unique result of Car.class you nedd set ResultTransformer

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class);
cr.createAlias("vendor", "vendor"); 

cr.add( Restrictions.eq("vendor.name", input));
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
results = (List<Car>) cr.list();
```